# How to handle math.random when there are multiple arrays?

Tags: arrays, math, random, floor

I have four arrays - flowers, trees, critters and songs.

I have four corresponding functions - flower(), tree(), critter() and song().

Within each individual function above, I have called my math.random function to retrieve a random word from the specific array.  For example, in my flower() function I have:

```
answer = flowers[Math.floor(Math.random() * flowers.length)];
```

I have found that in order for the random word to be generated, I also need to run my math.random function globally.  Here is my problem.  I don't know of a way to create the math.random function without assigning a variable.  So globally I have this:

```
function randomWord() {
  answer = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
}
```

So sometimes when I am in the flower category, a word from my flower array will show up - but sometimes a song will show up instead because I had to post it globally for it to work at all.

I am at a loss for how to fix it and while there are many questions regarding the math.floor function for arrays - I've not found any information on how to handle multiple arrays like this.

I'm wondering if there is a general word I could use instead of a specific variable word for the math.floor function that is called globally?  Or perhaps an if-else statement? I'm stuck and would appreciate any guidance.  Thank you.

Edited to add:

@KevinWallis this is pasted directly from my code:

```
let answer = "";


function randomWord() {
  answer = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
}


function flower() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("play").style.display = "block";
  answer = flowers[Math.floor(Math.random() * flowers.length)];
  word = flowers[answer];
  document.getElementById("categoryName").innerHTML = "Types of Flowers";
  updateTreePicture();
  randomWord();
  generateButtons();
  guessedWord();
}
```

UPDATE:  I just wanted to post what the fix ended up being:

```
function randomWord() {
  if (categoryName === 'Flowers') {
    answer = flowers[Math.floor(Math.random() * flowers.length)];
  } else if (categoryName === 'Trees') {
    answer = trees[Math.floor(Math.random() * trees.length)];
  } else if (categoryName === 'Critters') {
    answer = critters[Math.floor(Math.random() * critters.length)];
  } else if (categoryName === 'Songs') {
    answer = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code where you call the `randomWord()` function?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem but perhaps the concept of `return` will aid you.

Comment: depending on which condition do you select the random list?

Comment: and where do you call the `flower` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple `random` functions for songs, flowers, etc. Here is an example for calling such a random function and using the return value.

```
function randomSong() {
    songs = ...;
    return songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
}

function randomFlower() {
    flowers = ...;
    return flowers[Math.floor(Math.random() * flowers.length)];
}

...

function flower() {
    document.getElementById("main").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("play").style.display = "block";
    // use the selected flower instead of the global answer for all
    flower = randomFlower();
    document.getElementById("categoryName").innerHTML = "Types of Flowers";
    // e.g. the flower can be used as parameter
    updateTreePicture(flower);
    generateButtons();
    guessedWord();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
While this does work - it creates a bit of a problem other places in the code where randomWord() is needed.  For example - the button for Try Again (page refresh).  I would have to then assign a unique refresh button to each category.  Which I could do in this case - but it would seem cumbersome for projects with many more array options.  I appreciate the answer and will keep looking for a solution that wouldn't require individual assignments of code for each category when the same action is required for them all universally - I'm convinced it exists!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few main things that will be helpful for you to understand here and maybe stop you from focusing on storing everything in a single global variable as a method of accessing data everywhere:

1. You can return values from a function to use where you called the function.

```js
function getTheNumberOne(){
  return 1;
}

var theNumberOne = getTheNumberOne();
console.log(theNumberOne);
```

2. You can pass values to functions if you want to be able to use them in those functions.

```js
function getNumberPlusTen(number){
  return number + 10;
}

var numberPlusTen = getNumberPlusTen(5);
console.log(numberPlusTen);
```

3. There's a very lightweight library available at [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) that will make randomness simpler and more readable. It'll take a lot of the complexity out of your code and allow you to focus on the important things. All you have to do to use it is paste this `<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>` in the head tag of your html document, and then you'll be ready to deal with randomness as simply and readably as this:

```js
var flowers = ["rose", "sunflower", "tulip"];
var randomFlower = rando(flowers).value;

console.log(randomFlower);
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

4. If you must store values in global variables, an easy way not to get them all mixed together is to store them in separate variables. You're allowed to have more than one global variable!

```js
var flowers = ["rose", "sunflower", "tulip"];
var trees = ["birch", "oak", "maple"];

var randomFlower = "";
var randomTree = "";

function assignRandomValues(){
  randomFlower = rando(flowers).value;
  randomTree = rando(trees).value;
}

function logValues(){
  console.log(randomFlower);
  console.log(randomTree);
}

assignRandomValues();
logValues();
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

I can't give you any other advice because I haven't seen the rest of your code, but these concepts will guide you well.

Comment: Thank you very much - I appreciate all of this great information!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.

Comment: @jenkruk so which of the two answers helped solve your problem?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - please see the last section of my post where I updated it with the solution (if...else statement).  Thank you.